# Hardware lags and hangs in the latest Ubuntu

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, 22.04, budgie

I had a laptop which is little old. I was not using it for a long time but then I started using it again I needed it for some work. I installed Ubuntu latest version but the keyboard and mouse was stopping unexpectedly and I had to replug to use it for second and the same would happen it would freeze, so I thought maybe it's because of the latest version it's heavy so installed Budgie but the same is happening, and it's also the same with other flavors like Kali Linux, Lubuntu, Kylin. The wifi would stop after time of non-usage. I am running a server on it nodejs, the keyboard freezes and after sometimes it starts working itself, but when I press keys it misses also, everything else is working fine, plenty of CPU and RAM is available, but it's not working flawlessly. I tried Google, but it didn't help.

This is the output from `dmesg -T` :

[image]

Comment: Welcome to AU. Can you try to be a bit more specific? Edit your question with  details of your hardware and what you tried (from Google).

Comment: What type if hardware? if you could tell command

Comment: Do you see any problem in the Kernel? Run ```dmesg -T``` also you may post ```free -h``` you may not know and perhaps some processes are beinng OOM killed

Comment: Hi @CarlesMateo I have added the screenshot of result in question

Comment: Mem:           3.8Gi       1.3Gi       986Mi       236Mi       1.5Gi       2.1Gi
Swap:          7.4Gi          0B       7.4Gi
This is ```free -h``` results

Comment: Hi @WaseemMunir do you have the keyboard and mouse connected directly to USB ports or to an external USB multiport?

Comment: @CarlesMateo directly to usb ports , i have although tested out on external one same result, i was running window 7 on it , it was working fine, and the keyboard and mouse are also good as i use it on another laptop also sometimes, i have 4 usb ports i checked devices on all 4

Comment: Can you show which kernel version are you using? ```uname -a```

Comment: 5.15.0-40-generic  #43-Ubuntu SMPx86)64 GNU/LINUX